# Retrieve data from Account Server

Tags: c++, json

I'm trying to make a game launcher in C++ and I was wondering if I could get some guidance on how to carry out this task. Basically I've created an API which outputs the account data in JSON format.

i.e `{"success":true,"errorCode":0,"reason":"You're now logged in!"}`

```
http_fetch("http://www.example.com/api/login.php?username="+username+"&password="+password+"");
```

How am I able to retrieve the data?

Sorry if you don't understand. English isn't my first language :)

-brownzilla

Comment: Do you mean: "How can I extract the data from the JSON into a C++ model representation?", if so you could use a library to parse the JSON into such a format (Picojson, etc.) or write a parser yourself.

Comment: Yes! That is what I meant! Sorry haha :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for a library that allows you to parse Json. Some examples:

- [Picojson](https://github.com/kazuho/picojson)
- [Rapidjson](https://code.google.com/p/rapidjson/)

Both are quite easy to use and allow you to turn json into a model that can later be used to map to your own model. Alternatively you could write your own Json parser though that would be a bit of work (reinventing the wheel perhaps).

Comment: Will this help retrieve JSON data from a `.php` script?

Comment: `Basically I've created an API` - I assume the call to the php file (http_fetch) returns the specified JSON. Assuming it does you can just parse that JSON.